# Android Studio on MacOS : AVD button is grayed

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am a complete beginner of Android Studio and I'm trying to create my first Hello World program unfortunately I can't click on AVD Manager icon as it was disabled on my mac. Hope someone can enlighten me what should I do to get it turn on.

Much appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You will require system images to download, It will make the avd manager available for you for creating new divices on it.

---

best advice is let you update it with selecting all components and let it download and make that all available for you.

---

Be cautious. you should have java installed on your mac before installing android studio. Android studio will automatically find the path of your installed java and will complete its installation.

---

How to install and update on mac? Once you open android studio, Look below on main small screen, configure->dropdown-> sdk manager and update